# How can I adjust the width of the inner element so that it word wraps naturally?

Tags: css, width, word-wrap

In the example below, I would like word wrap only to happen if the left side of `position-me` hits the left side of the screen [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNihU.png).

I think that currently `#position-me` inherits the width of the parent element  and even if I set `width: auto !important;` in `#position-me` it still wraps at the parent width.

If I set `white-space: nowrap;` on `#position-me` then it overrides the 100px width, but the text overruns the div (and the page potentially!)

```css
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#position-me {  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
This is the wrapper div
    <div id='position-me'>
        Text is here and it is great, I wonder when it will decide to wrap itself?
    </div>  
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pfa89bu1/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a big negative margin left, limit the width to the width of the screen minus the red box width and use bottom/right for the position:

```css
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#position-me {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-left: -200vmax;
  max-width: calc(100vw - 100%);
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  This is the wrapper div
  <div id='position-me'>
    Text is here and it is great, I wonder when it will decide to wrap itself?
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah in this case the width of the red box is not set at 100px, it could be variable. I should have changed that in my example, sorry, I will update it now.

Comment: @BenHolness it need to be fixed or known, otherwise you will need JS in this case

Comment: @BenHolness nevermind, it can be done with CSS ;) forget that the 100% will refer to the parent width (check the update)